# empty output parameter from parameter arraylist (enterprise library 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

Trying to implement Enterprise Library v.6 Data Access Blocks. Former code (using Sqlhelper from MS Application Blocks) made use of SqlParameter array, but that's causing a lot of issues. Instead using the ArrayList works fine on all other EL 6 updated methods of the application except below when trying to catch an output parameter to be returned along with the dataset.

Result is properly returned from the Stored Procedure (shows up at command level), but not captured properly (empty at totalRecords = ...) . Anyone have any advise? (note: the use of command.parameter.add etc. is no option, must be solved with below setup). Thanks in advance.

```
    public InvitationQueueData GetVotersInvitationQueue(int surveyId, int pageNumber, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            InvitationQueueData dataSet = new InvitationQueueData();

// Former code:
            //SqlParameter[] commandParameters = new SqlParameter[] 
            //{ new SqlParameter("@SurveyID", surveyId), 
            //    new SqlParameter("@CurrentPage", pageNumber), 
            //    new SqlParameter("@PageSize", pageSize), 
            //    new SqlParameter("@TotalRecords", SqlDbType.Int) };

            //commandParameters[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

//New code:    
            ArrayList commandParameters = new ArrayList();
            {
                commandParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TotalRecords", SqlDbType.Int){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }.SqlValue);
                commandParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SurveyId", surveyId).SqlValue);
                commandParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CurrentPage", pageNumber).SqlValue);
                commandParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PageSize", pageSize).SqlValue);
            }

            DbConnection.db.LoadDataSet("vts_spVoterInvitationQueueGetAll", dataSet, new string[] {"InvitationQueues"}, commandParameters.ToArray());

            totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(commandParameters[0].ToString());

            return dataSet;
        }
```

Comment: I find it strange to pass the total records as a parameter and expect it to be populated. Are you sure it is not like "long totalRecords = DbConnection.db.LoadDataSet(...);"?

Comment: I am using Enterprise Library 3.1 and I'm running into the same issue where the out parameter is always blank even through the execution of the stored procedure is successful. Did you find a solution to your problem?